# Python: cannot remove \n

Tags: python, strip

I want to remove `\n` from the beginning lines like this `\n  id int(10) NOT NULL`. I tried `strip()`, `rstrip()`, `lstrip()` `replace('\n', '')`. I don't get it. What am I doing wrong?

```
print(column)
print(column.__class__)
x = column.rstrip('\n')
print(x)
x = column.lstrip('\n')
print(x)            
x = column.strip('\n')          
print(x)
print(repr(column))
```

gives

```
\n  id int(10) NOT NULL
<type 'str'>
\n  id int(10) NOT NULL
\n  id int(10) NOT NULL
\n  id int(10) NOT NULL
\n  id int(10) NOT NULL
'\\n  `id` int(10) NOT NULL'
```

Comment: Dunno. Why don't you show some actual code?

Comment: Source code or it didn't happen! ;)

Comment: .. of the three possibilities, `strip()`, `.rstrip()`, and `.lstrip()`, you gave output from the only one of them which wouldn't strip an initial `\n`.  Could you show the output from the others? (And `repr(column)`.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure that `\n` is a newline instead of a literal `\` followed by a literal `n`?  In that case, you'd want:

```
s = r'\nthis is a string'
s = s.strip()
print s
s = s.strip(r'\n')
print s
```

Probably a better way is to check if it starts with `\n` before stripping, and then use slicing:

```
if s.startswith(r'\n'): s = s[2:]
```

or even more robustly, `re.sub`:

```
re.sub(r'^(?:\\n)+','',r'\n\nfoobar')
```

Based on the symptoms you describe above, I'm almost positive this is the case.

Comment: It looks like you win this round!  To soothe my wounded pride, I'll point out that `s.strip(r'\n')` is a little dangerous because it would also strip initial `n`s..

Comment: @DSM Even though this seems to have won out I would keep yours around because people could easily have your problem too. I thought you were joking when you said you'd delete it.

Comment: @DSM -- I was lucky this time.  We were both just guessing. I've updated with a more robust solution using `re` as I can't put a better solution together without it...